# Using hasattr() when the attribute is not known

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to combine two applications for visualising binaries, binvis and droidcolors. Since droidcolors is in C, I'm trying to make binvis replicate the functionality offered by droidcolors.

Here are the relevant snippets from the code that I've written so far. The complete file is here: https://pastebin.com/0C7fu9W2.

```
class _Color:
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        self.data = data
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        s = list(set(data))
        s.sort()
        self.symbol_map = {v : i for (i, v) in enumerate(s)}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def point(self, x):
        if hasattr(self, 'class_defs') and (self.class_defs[0] <= x <= self.class_defs[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_classdefs(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'dat') and (self.dat[0] <= x <= self.dat[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_data(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'field_ids') and (self.field_ids[0] <= x <= self.field_ids[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_field_ids(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'header') and (self.header[0] <= x <= self.header[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_header(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'links') and (self.links[0] <= x <= self.links[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_links(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'proto_ids') and (self.proto_ids[0] <= x <= self.proto_ids[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_proto_ids(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'method_ids') and (self.method_ids[0] <= x <= self.method_ids[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_method_ids(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'string_ids') and (self.string_ids[0] <= x <= self.string_ids[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_string_ids(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'type_ids') and (self.type_ids[0] <= x <= self.type_ids[1]):
            return self.return_droidcolors_type_ids(x)
        elif hasattr(self, 'block') and (self.block[0] <= x <= self.block[1]):
            return self.block[2]
        else:
            return self.getPoint(x)

# --- snip ---

class ColorDroidColors(_Color):
    def getPoint(self, x):
        return [0, 0, 0]

# --- snip ---

dex_handle = Dexparser(args[0])
dex_header_info = dex_handle.header_info()

dex_class_defs = (dex_header_info['class_defs_off'], dex_header_info['class_defs_off'] + (64 * dex_header_info['class_defs_size']) - 1)
dex_data       = (dex_header_info['data_off'], dex_header_info['data_off'] + dex_header_info['data_size'] - 1)
dex_field_ids  = (dex_header_info['field_ids_off'], dex_header_info['field_ids_off'] + (8 * dex_header_info['field_ids_size']) - 1)
dex_header     = (0x0, dex_header_info['header_size'] - 1)
dex_links      = (link_off, link_off + dex_header_info['link_size'] - 1)
dex_proto_ids  = (dex_header_info['proto_ids_off'], dex_header_info['proto_ids_off'] + (12 * dex_header_info['proto_ids_size']) - 1)
dex_method_ids = (dex_header_info['method_ids_off'], dex_header_info['method_ids_off'] + (8 * dex_header_info['method_ids_size']) - 1)
dex_string_ids = (dex_header_info['string_ids_off'], dex_header_info['string_ids_off'] + (4 * (dex_header_info['string_ids_size']) - 1))
dex_type_ids   = (dex_header_info['type_ids_off'], dex_header_info['type_ids_off'] + (4 * dex_header_info['type_ids_size']) - 1)

kwarg_dict = {
    "class_defs": dex_class_defs,
    "dat": dex_data,
    "field_ids": dex_field_ids,
    "header": dex_header,
    "links": dex_links,
    "proto_ids": dex_proto_ids,
    "method_ids": dex_method_ids,
    "string_ids": dex_string_ids,
    "type_ids": dex_type_ids,
    }

for i, item in enumerate(dex_handle.protoids_list()):
    if item[2]:
        kwarg_dict['dex_proto_params_' + str(i)] = (item[2], (0x0 + item[2]) * 4 + 4)

csource = ColorDroidColors(
    d,
    **kwarg_dict
)
```

I'm basically passing 10000+ kwargs to a method, and require a way to test within the method if a kwarg exists and depending on the same, to return some value. All the kwargs have a particular prefix, followed by sequential numbers starting from 1. I tried using a for loop, but that slowed the program down to a crawl.

Could anyone please suggest me a way out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getattr()` and a list of attributes to test:

```
attrs = ['class_defs', 'dat', 'field_ids', ..., 'block']
for name in attrs:
    value = getattr(self, name, None)
    if value is not None and value[0] <= x <= value[1]
        if name != 'block':
            method_name = 'return_droidcolors_' + name
            return getattr(self, method_name)(x)
        else:
            return value[2]

# none of the attributes matched
return self.getPoint(x)
```

Note that in your `__init__` method, you could just use `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` rather than loop through the dictionary and call `setattr()` each time.

Comment: The thing is, I'm generating the attribute names on the fly, using the `for i, item in enumerate(dex_handle.protoids_list()):` construct. As such, I do not know beforehand how many attributes might get generated. I can create a list named `attrs` using fixed attributes and a list comprehension, but there's always the possibility that I might miss out on attributes.

Comment: @D.De: then you can generate the `attrs` list too.

Comment: Could you please tell me how? At this point, all that comes to my mind is: `attrs = ['block', 'class_defs', 'dat', 'field_ids', 'header', 'links', 'proto_ids', 'method_ids', 'string_ids', 'type_ids'] + ['proto_params_' + str(i) for i in range(15000)]`. But since I'm using a fixed parameter for `range()`, there's a chance I might miss out on attributes if more than 15000 items match the conditional, `if item[2]:`.

Comment: @D.De: So how does Dexparser know what attributes are available? I can't help with that; you did not lay out why you think you need numbered attributes Your question is getting less clear with the minute, I'm afraid.

Comment: @D.De: it might, if you know the pattern to look for. `dir()` is a much broader list than just the direct instance attributes, see [what's the biggest difference between dir and \_\_dict\_\_ in python](//stackoverflow.com/a/14361362). You could use `vars(self)` instead, that gives you a dictionary.

Comment: @D.De: you'd still have to skip `symbol_map` and `data` attributes there.

Comment: It doesn't. Basically, there can be any number of prototype parameters inside a DEX file. I'm passing them to the point() method as keyword arguments. Since the number of protoype parameters varies from one DEX file to another, I used numbered attributes.